# Report Builder MAP Parameters

Tags: dictionary, reporting-services, report

Good Afternoon,
So I have built a State Map in Report builder that is separated into Counties. I have been pretty successful, however there is one thing I cannot figure out. When I click on the county, is it possible to pass the county name that I clicked to a chart on the same report. I can pass it to another report via go to report, but I would like to have it on the same document.I also kept getting a Subreport not found when I attempted that method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic rule of SSRS is that with very few exceptions, you cannot change the content of a report unless you refresh the report.

Bearing this in mind, you have a couple of options..

### Call the same report again as a subreport.

Assuming you only want your map and a single dynamic chart.

- Add a parameter to the report that defaults to specific value such as 'none'. Then you can decide what do show in your chart when the parameter = 'none' or you could choose the hide the chart if the parameter is 'none'.
- In your map go to the map's polygon properties and assign an action.
- Set the action to be Go to Report
- Choose your report (so we get the report to call itself)
- Add a parameter, choose the parameter you added a few steps earlier as the name and select the field that contains the state name or ID etc as the value.
- Your Chart's dataset can then be updated to use the new parameter in the dataset query.

### Create a chart for every State

The other option is to create a chart for every state, you can do this using a table or list control and a subreport containing your chart, so you design will not have to have lots of charts individually placed.
Each Chart can have a bookmark set (most objects have a bookmark property) that is the name or ID of the state it represents.
Then in your map, set the action properties in the polygon properties to 'Go to bookmark' and then use the state name or ID as the bookmark expression to go to.

Comment: Thank you Alan for the response. Everything makes sense, However I keep getting a "Parameter not defined error." Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you took the first option then? You will probably need to edit your question and show the report design including the parameter properties and also the action properties on the polygon. It sounds like the parameter you are trying to assign does not exist of the name is incorrect/wrong case etc. but if you share what you have so far I might be able to help

Comment: So I'll do my best here. Thank you for your patience. I have an individual state that is divided into counties. I have a hidden parameter set to 'none' like you mentioned. The parameter is named "County". I mapped the sub report to go to the main report as you mentioned and set the parameter @County to equal the county that is clicked. Thats when I get the error

Comment: Alan, Thank you again I figured out my issue. I did not have the Parameter Name Specified in the SQL code.

Comment: No problem. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons to the left) as this also helps other SO users looking for answers to similar questions.